# Deploying a Windows Azure app from the Command Line?

Tags: node.js, command-line, azure

I checked out smarx's [noderole](https://github.com/smarx/noderole)/[packanddeploy](https://github.com/smarx/packanddeploy) and want to test it locally, then deploy it to Azure, but without using Visual Studio. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy using the Windows Azure Portal or by using PowerShell. First you'll need to use  **cspack.exe** to create the service package like you'll find in smarx's **packanddeploy** (more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx)

Once you have the package, you can upload it through the Windows Azure Portal or use the PowerShell cmdlets. The training kit comes with an exercise to deploy using PowerShell: [Exercise 2: Using PowerShell to Manage Windows Azure Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg271300)

Comment: No, the example you can find in the training kit is based on the following: http://wappowershell.codeplex.com

Comment: Btw, another great option is to use Steve Marx's [`waz-cmd`](https://github.com/smarx/waz-cmd).